# Argument type mismatch error in maven spring mvc

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

Hi guys i am trying to learn maven. I have this working project in spring mvc 3.1 that i need to convert it into maven 3.2.1. Everything was working well before but after i converted this project to maven i am getting this error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I dont know whats wrong i cant even debug as the control doesnot even enter into the function.Here are my codes

**jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Add New Movie Detail</title>
        <style>
            .detail{
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
            .detail td{
                width: 300px;
                border:1px solid #999999
            }
            .detail td input{
                width:300px;
            }
            .message{
                width:300px;
                margin:0 auto;
                background-color: #66ff66;
                text-align: center;
                padding:5px;
            }
            .errors{
                color:#ff3333
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <c:if test="${not empty msg }">
            <div class="message">
                <span class="message-text">${msg }</a>
            </div>
        </c:if>  
        <form:form method="POST" action="insertMovie.do" modelAttribute="newMovie">
            <table class="detail">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Movie Name:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:input path="movie_name"/>
                        <span class="errors">
                            <form:errors path="movie_name"/>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Actor Name:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:input path="actor"/>
                        <span class="errors">
                            <form:errors path="actor"/>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Actress Name:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:input path="actress"/>
                        <span class="errors">
                            <form:errors path="actress"/>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Director Name:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:input path="director"/>
                        <span class="errors">
                            <form:errors path="director"/>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="./moviedetail.view">Go back to movie detail</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

**controller** i am posting only the function thats dependent

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/newmovie.view")
    public String insertNewMovie(@ModelAttribute("newMovie") Movie movie, ModelMap model) {
        model.put(BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX + "newMovie",
                model.get("errors"));
        return "newmovie";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/insertMovie.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addNewMovie(@Valid @ModelAttribute("newMovie") Movie movie, BindingResult result, ModelMap model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttr) {
        System.out.println("Movie name " + movie.getMovie_name());
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            redirectAttr.addFlashAttribute("errors", result);
            redirectAttr.addFlashAttribute("newMovie", movie);
            return "redirect:newmovie.view";
        }
        mdao.insertMovieDetail(movie);
        redirectAttr.addFlashAttribute("msg", "Your Data has been successfully entered");
        return "redirect:newmovie.view";
    }
```

**pom.xml** file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.moveez</groupId>
    <artifactId>Moveez</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Moveez</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>gfv3ee6</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency> 

        <!-- Hibernate validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.util.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-4.3.1.Final</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>              
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.18</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>Moveez</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

**I want to remind u once again that this project is working fine without maven.**

Comment: You're saying with maven and with Spring version 3.1.1 it **isn't** working?

Comment: Also, what request URL is it failing on?

Comment: After implementation of maven it isn't working...previously the project worked well with spring 3.1.1

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis when use submits new movie form it must call function mapped with `/insertMovie.do` request

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I think its important to tell that the form is properly loading but when i try to submit a new movie i get the exception i have mentioned in the question

Comment: Does it work without `@Valid`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis actually i am having problem with `RedirectAtrributes`. I have its necessary dependency. I checked it.

Comment: Can you check with adding javax.validation also as dependency.

Comment: @apurvc Wouldn't it fail at compile time when the dependency was missing?

Comment: `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` is deprecated in Spring MVC 3.2. Do you explicitly add this `HandlerAdapter` to your context? If so try to leave it out and use `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Valid is part of validation-api as far as I know and I don't see that included as dependency in pom.

Comment: @apurvc Probably the second dependency showing in the POM. Spring is not so picky about the annotation since it will validate any model attribute annotated with an annotation that starts with `"Valid"` in the name.